# How to hide header component in login page reactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-redux

Am new to ReactJS. I want to hide header component in Login page and show in inner pages. I have an App.js  I have used ternary operator but not working.

```
class App extends Component {
    render(){
    let HideHeader = EmployeeLogin ? null : <HeaderNavContainer />
        return (
            <div>
                <Router history={history}>
                    <div>                    
                        {HideHeader}
                        <Switch>
                            <Route path="/about" component={About} />
                            <Route path="/EmployeeLogin" component={EmployeeLogin} />                        
                            <Route path="/MyPreferences" component={MyPreferences} />                        
                            <Route component={PageNotFound} />
                        </Switch>    
                    </div>    
                </Router>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

If EmployeeLogin component is rendered I want to hide header navigation
 `<HeaderNavContainer />` if not  I want to show `<HeaderNavContainer />`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the `render` method of your `HeaderNavContainer`, you can do this:

```
render() {
  if (window.location.pathname === '/EmployeeLogin') return null;
  return <insert your header nav code>;
}
```

Since `HeaderNavContainer` is wrapped within `<Router>`, it'll re-render when `window.location.pathname` changes.

Alternatively, add `HeaderNavContainer` to your `About`, `MyPreferences` etc instead of putting in `App`.

Answer (score 4):

In  component you can check if the `history.location.pathname` is equal to `/EmployeeLogin` and then return null. You can use `withReducer` for getting history object as a prop.

```
render(){
  if(this.props.history.location.pathname==='/EmployeeLogin'){
    return null;
  }   
  return (//your navigation component code.)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking component exists or not try to check the URL is hit or not

In window.location.pathname you will get the current URL.

let HideHeader = window.location.pathname === 'your need string' ? null :

Answer (score 0):

Create a HideHeader route that renders (conditionally) the Header component and an Outlet component for the nested route components.

```
import { Outlet, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { Header } from "./Header";

const HideHeader = ({ hideHeaderPaths }) => {
const { pathName } = useLocation();

return (
 <>
   {!hideHeaderPaths.includes(pathName) && <Header />}
   <Outlet />
 </>
 );
};
```

export default HideHeader;

In **App.js**

import your **HideHeader.js**

```
import HideHeader from "./common/HideHeader"
...
...
<Route element={<HideHeader hideHeaderPaths={["/login"]} />}></Route>
```

and import your header on those pages where you want to show

```
<Header />
```